# SNMPWalk module not found

Tags: snmp

I am currently trying to get extended output on SNMPWalk.

I have installed snmp-mibs downloader and have been running download-mibs.

I am using the following command:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public [ip] -m NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendObjects
```

and get the following error:

```
MIB search path:
/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/var/lib/mibs:/var/lib/mibs/ietf:/var/lib/mibs/iana
Cannot find module (nsExtendObjects): At line 1 in (none)
```

I can confirm that my modules are in the right place, as I have verified manually.

I have tried using -M to specify the location of modules.

I use NET-SNMP version: 5.9

After the error, I get the same output as if I did not use extended mode.

I can also confirm that there should be a different output, as another machine using the same configuration is able to get extended output. The "public" string is the right one.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Seems like this particular module is located in different place (if installed at all)

Comment: I have actually found it in the folders that are specified, and have added extra folders where it also is.

IF it is not installed, would you have any idea how I could install this specific one ?

Answer (score 0):

The `-m` option takes a parameter: a colon-separated list of *MIB module names*, not the names of individual MIB objects.

As a result, `-m NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendObjects` gets parsed as three MIB module names:

- `NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB` which is a valid MIB module name
- `<null>` which is apparently ignored
- `nsExtendObjects` which is actually the name of a MIB object within the NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB module.

Specifying the OID to start walking from is actually optional for `snmpwalk`: if it is not specified, it will default to  `SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2` and that's why you are not getting an error message about bad syntax. Instead, the command tries to look for a MIB module named `nsExtendObjects` and obviously does not find one.

If you want to keep using the `-m` option for some reason, the correct syntax would be:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public [ip] -m NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendObjects
```

In other words, the first `NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB` is a parameter for the `-m` option, and the second is part of the OID you wish to start walking at.

But in this case, you probably can just omit the `-m` option altogether:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public [ip] NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendObjects
```

Both these forms should produce the same result.

If `download-mibs` has been successfully completed, you should have a file named `/usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt` on your system.

```
$ sha256sum /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
ad05abc5ec39107a140d46e4e62e3fc0cf38eb26c1abe634fd7e9a7c7715e64e  /usr/share/snmp/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB.txt
```

Comment: Hi!
First of all, thank you for your detailed answer.

`snmpwalk -v2c -c public [ip] NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendObjects` was actually the way i had attempted at first, which raised me a different error ("Timeout: no response from [IP]" or something similar).

My VM on which i was attempting this just died (RIP), I'll keep searching on this topic on the coming days and will verify whether this explaination has made everything right :) !

Thanks again